# PyTorch looking up indices (tracing a path) as tensor operations

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

How could the following be written as a Tensor operation without a loop?

```py
a = torch.Tensor([[0, 1, 1],
                  [2, 1, 0],
                  [1, 0, 1]]).long()
trace = torch.zeros(4, dtype=torch.long)

start_idx = 0
trace[0] = start_idx

for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    trace[i + 1] = a[i, trace[i]]

print(trace)
# tensor([0, 0, 2, 1])
```

The code basically traces a given tensor. Starting with `start_idx` we are iteratively looking up the next index in the tensor to add to our trace.